# iOS Web App not working properly

Tags: html, ios, safari

I'm trying to make an extremely basic web app for iOS. apple-mobile-web-app-capable does not allow my app to be run in standalone mode. I've followed Apple's own tutorial to set this up and have been surfing the web for a solution for too long at this point. I've tried clearing the cache and re-adding the app. I also tried removing the meta tag and altering it and then setting it back along with removing the bookmark, which was mentioned in another answer and it did nothing for me.

Anybody have a solution?

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test App</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Test App">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <style>
      #testButton {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        font-size: 500%;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function output(){
        alert("window.navigator.standalone = " +  window.navigator.standalone);
      }
    </script>
    <button id="testButton" onclick="output()">Test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you define "*not working properly*" please? What is the expected behaviour? What happens instead?

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear what is not working. Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue as you in the past. Apparently web apps don't work as expected since iOS 9 (i believe); however, I've found you can solve it with the tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
<meta name="apple-mobile-app-capable" content="yes">
```

It worked for me, hope it does as well for you ;)